# Page continues loading forever

Tags: bug

I've been noticing lately (and so far spontaneously) that just about any page on Stack Overflow continues loading infinitely. I mean everything loads and works, but the browser (Chrome) keeps going on and on as if it's still busy. I do have AdBlockPlus, but even disabling that doesn't seem to stop this loading.

[image: Chrome tab waiting]

**UPDATE**

After the answer below by lostsock, I observed what shows in the bottom-left corner of Chrome. One instance was right on, `http://*.quantserve.com`. However, although I've blocked that particular domain, it still continues to occur for other domain names (such as www.google-analytics.com), as well as installed extensions (AdBlockPlus, ModifyHeaders, etc.). Sometimes it just says `Connecting...` or even nothing at all. Dev tools (in the Network tab) shows everything has loaded (except for the few which have been blocked).

**UPDATE 2**

I realized that this first of all only happens after a browser window has been open for a long period of time (regardless of how many times you click links or refresh the page). Once it starts, it never stops. But it takes a while for it to start in the first place. While it's happening in one browser window (or tab), I may have another tab open to the same page without the issue. Only way to get rid of it is to close that browser window/tab and re-open it in a new one.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior (I'm also using chrome).

Comment: Just because one person can't recreate it doesn't mean it's a poor question. Why the downvote/close?

Comment: Does it not list in the bottom left corner what domain it's waiting for? It might help land the blame on adverts, CDN, etc.

Comment: In the network tab of the dev tools can you see any uncompleted requests?

Comment: I'm waiting for it to happen again so I can check. It doesn't happen all the time, but maybe 5 or so times a day.

Comment: I have seen what sounds like potentially the same thing a number of times. The page looked like it had loaded just fine, but the tab title was still saying something like "Waiting for...". I believe it was on my Windows machine using IE.

Comment: Two different people have recreated the issue yet people are still voting to close as "no longer reproducable"?

Comment: I don't see why this would be a SO or SE bug. Your browser is incapable of communicating it's state to you, the user. I don't think SE has any control over that, do they?

Comment: @Sumurai8 Except that it only happens on Stack Overflow (not even SE, MSE, MSO, etc... Only on SO).

Comment: It happens to me too like you descriped it in the UPDATE 2 - not on stackoverflow, on my own page. After a long time it starts and never goes away. When I open the same page in a new tab its gone.

Comment: This is happening to me as well, but it's not just on Stack Overflow. This issue occurs for me spontaneously on many websites; however, I do believe it happens most frequently for me on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This isn't actually a Stack Overflow related issue. I only sometimes visit the site and yet get these random loading moments on any random site at any random moment. I highly suspect it is an issue in Chrome and not the website.

Comment: @DaVince I'm only seeing this problem with Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue happening because of quantserve.com

I just blocked quantserve.com, and the issue has stopped.

In adBlockPlus, just add your own custom filter, so that it blocks it.

For example:

Go to filter preferences, then custom filter tab, then click add filter and put this in there

```
http://*.quantserve.com
```

If for some reason this isn't the site that is causing the issue. Just find the one that is with your developer tools and block that one; and hopefully whichever site that is won't hurt your browsing/SE experience by blocking it.

Comment: I did notice one of the times it was showing this precise domain. So I added it to the filter as suggested, and that one doesn't appear anymore. However, it appears more things are affecting it than just that one, including various different installed extensions, other domain names, and sometimes only says `Connecting...` with no domain.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing cookies for the individual website resolved the problem for me (not on Stack Overflow but on another site with the same issue).

Comment: had the same issue with a site from compary I work for. opened incognito mode (or clearing the cookies) solved the problem. we couldnt find any pending request on the browser, and we were afraid it was related to our load balance or anything similar. nothing found.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the tab, and using another one, or restart the entire browser solved this issue. I am guessing, that maybe some gif image get stuck there, instead of being replaced with the favicon after page loading has finished.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but my Problem was Google Chrome Version. For 52.0.2743.82 it was working fine, for version 61, 62, 66 it was loading continuously. I Will update my comment later if have any other findings.
(Note : It was working fine on Mozilla Firefox.)